# {Binding}, {Binding Data.XXX}, {Binding Path=XXX} and others in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I followed different tutorials and example and they showed me those different type of binding but I can't understand when to use one and when use another.

For example sometimes I see simply:

```
Binding="{Binding}"
```

Sometimes (and this I understand how to use it) after setting the `DataContext`:

```
Binding="{Binding Propriety1}"
```

In DevExpress GridControl i see:

```
Binding="{Binding Data.ProprietyName}"
```

And others.
Can one explain shortly and clear why so different cases? I searched online but the tutorials say only what binding is (and I know what is) and a simple example like the third I wrote.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

K here's the simple explanation you asked for:

```
Binding="{Binding}"
```

that is when you're binding the `DataContext` object itself. So whatever is the `DataContext` in the current scope where the binding is what is being bound. that can also be written as `Binding="{Binding .}"`

Next:

```
Binding="{Binding Propriety1}"
```

Here you're binding `Propriety1` within the current `DataContext`. This one is the same as `{Binding DataContext.Propriety1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />`

Finally:

```
Binding="{Binding Data.ProprietyName}"
```

Here you're binding `ProprietyName` which belongs to `Data` which is a property declared in the current `DataContext`

All these are shown in this example: [Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3wo7sadmdwsg1o/BindingTypes.rar)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding TestStringOne}"
              Text="{Binding}" />
  <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding TestStringOne}"
              Text="{Binding .}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestStringTwo}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.TestStringThree}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The properties and `Data` object's class you can find in `MainViewModel.cs` for these