# WPF ContentTemplate empty binding {Binding}

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I'm learning WPF. I'm confused about empty binding, aka {binding}.
In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323285/binding-binding-data-xxx-binding-path-xxx-and-others-in-wpf), I learnt that this means binding to the DataContext object itself, But in the below code, I couldn't find the related DataContext. Since it's not very short, the full code is in [this link](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/17/11183144/DOWNLOAD/Chapter16Code.zip), KarliCard GUI project.

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="SuitTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <Label x:Name="SuitLabel"
        Content="{Binding Path=Suit, ElementName=UserControl, Mode=Default}"
        ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource SuitTemplate}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
```

The result is that, this Label SuitLabel shows the Content "Suit" in the textblock. But in the whole xaml or code behind, I don't find any DataContext in that UserControl scope
So my question is, is this empty binding  still binding to some DataContext? Or in this scenario, the binding source is the Content of the label?

Comment: The implicit `DataContext` inside `DataTemplate` in your code is actually the `Content` of `Label`.

Comment: @KingKing. Thank you, I think that answers my question